# Dialyzer: Unknown Type re:mp()

Tags: erlang, specifications, dialyzer

In this contrived example, the `parsing` module offers a function called `parse_equation/2`, which accepts an equation to be parsed, and a regular expression pattern to be used for said parsing:

```erlang
-module(parsing).
-export([parse_equation/2]).

parse_equation(Equation, Pattern) ->
    {match, [_, Left, Right]} = re:run(Equation, Pattern, [{capture, all, binary}]),
    {Left, Right}.
```

This works as intended:

```
$ erl
1> c(parsing).
{ok,parsing}
2> {ok, Pattern} = re:compile("^(.+) = (.+)$").
{ok, ...}
3> parsing:parse_equation("1 + 1 = 2", Pattern).
{<<"1 + 1">>,<<"2">>}
```

I'd like to add a type specification to `parse_equation/2`. According to the `re` manpage,`Pattern` is of type `mp()`, i.e. `re:mp()` from my module. So this is my spec:

```erlang
-spec parse_equation(string(), re:mp()) -> {binary(), binary()}.
```

However, the `dialyzer` cannot make sense of that specification:

```
$ dialyzer parsing.erl 
  Checking whether the PLT /home/patrick/.cache/erlang/.dialyzer_plt is up-to-date... yes
  Proceeding with analysis...
Unknown types:
  re:mp/0 (/home/patrick/github.com/patrickbucher/learning-erlang/dialyzer-issue/parsing.erl:4:32)
 done in 0m0.14s
done (warnings were emitted)
```

How can I make the type `re:mp()` known to the `dialyzer`? I *did* run `dialyzer --build_plt --apps erts kernel stdlib` before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.erl` does [define the `mp/0` type](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/12ca3da107281fe672b8b6f93f52c8556b66c218/lib/stdlib/src/re.erl#L23), but since there is no `-export_type` declaration (described in the docs [here](https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html#type-declarations-of-user-defined-types)), it is not available to other modules.  (See also [this Github issue](https://github.com/erlang/otp/issues/5280))

To make the type `re:mp()` available, you'd need to add `-export_type` there.

---

In fact, there is [a pull request](https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/7999) that does that. So most likely this will work correctly once Erlang/OTP 27 is released.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue! However, adding the `-export_type` declaration is no option, because that's part of the Erlang standard library. So what would you suggest to do in practice?

Comment: The best I can think of is to copy the type definition into your own module...

Comment: BTW, I found a bug report about this: https://github.com/erlang/otp/issues/5280

Comment: Thanks @legscia; the bug report says it all. (I'm just learning Erlang, so the missing spec isn't a big issue. It's just for my understanding.)